# PHP - PDO error

Tags: php

I'm getting an error with PDO:

> PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, pseudo, ip, date) VALUES ('mykeyperso', 'mrthebigbosseur', '86.208.78.145',' at line 1 in /home/a1394006/public_html/api/skype.php on line 51

And I don't know why

My source code:

```
 $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO logs (key, pseudo, ip, date) VALUES (:key, :pseudo, :ip, :date)');
$req->bindParam(":key", $key1, PDO::pARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam(":pseudo", $pseudo1, PDO::pARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam(":ip", $ip1, PDO::pARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam(":date", $date, PDO::pARAM_STR);
$req->execute();
```

My variable:

```
 $key1 = $_GET['key'];
$pseudo1 = $_GET['pseudo'];
$ip1 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
```

My database: http://prntscr.com/6zjsmd

So if someone can help me plz

Comment: I'll give you a clue... it starts with a lower case p

Comment: What.. ? Can you explain me plz

Comment: Plus, `pARAM_STR` all of those I'm sure are case-senstive. `PARAM_STR`

Answer (score 1):

Key is a reserved word in mysql. To use it as a column name, wrap it in backticks (`key`). Double quotes would apparently also work in ANSI SQL mode.

Comment: *wrap it in quotes* in which quotes `'` or `"` or \` ...?

Comment: Or try to avoid using reserved words in the first place, if it all possible.

Comment: Double quotes, or as @andrewsi rightly points out, try not to use them in the first place.

Comment: @JonStirling *Errr.* You had a change from 33.333...%. And you're wrong! You have to put \` around them!

Comment: @Rizier123 Actually that depends on the configuration. But as a rule you're correct. Updating.